# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $username = $conn->escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $middlename = $conn->escape_string($_POST['middlename']);
    $surname = $conn->escape_string($_POST['surname']);
    $lastname = $conn->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

    /*foreach($_POST as $post){
        if($post == '')
            $error['login'] = "No field should be left blank";
    }*/

    if(strlen($_POST['user']) < 5){
        $error['username'] = 'username is too short';
    } else{
        $stmt->prepare('SELECT username from admin where `username` = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['user']);
        $stmt->bind_result($user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        if($_POST['user'] == $user){
            $error['username'] = 'This username has been registered already';
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
    }

    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmPassword']){
        $error['password'] = 'password does not match';

    }elseif(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
        $error['password'] = 'password is too short';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['surname']) < 2){
        $error['surname'] = 'surname is too short';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['middlename']) < 2){
        $error['middlename'] = 'surname is too short';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['lastname']) < 2){
        $error['lastname'] = 'surname is too short';
    }

    if(count($error) == 0){
        include('./../core/connect.php');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO admin (username, password, surname, middlename, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $surname, $firstname, $lastname);
        $stmt->execute();
        $success = $stmt->affected_rows;
    }}
```

I am having problem with code and I have searched google and documntations without success. I have made sure that i didnt use single quote with question marks (?) in prepared statement and I have tried to var_dump the $_POST super array and still I cannot find the error. The only thing I noticed is that my $_POST['user'] is  written as 
'user'=> &string 'stanley' (length=6)

Comment: So... Let's talk about `$firstname` - Where does it come from?

Comment: all came from a form registration form a created

Comment: Yes, but try to search for `$firstname` in the provided code, where do you declare it exactly?

Comment: Thanks I have corrected the code still error

Comment: It should work then, based on the code in the question. Are you sure you're debugging the correct line of code (Which line of code is it anyway?)

Comment: And BTW, don't do `$conn->escape_string` on the variables since you're using prepared statements